# Rust convert &[u8] to [u8; SIZE]

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

If I have a variable of type `&[u8]`, is there a way to turn it instead into type `[u8; SIZE]` where SIZE is some fixed constant?

Comment: In general no but you can match it, can you give any example ?